# Property rights: the power of testimonial disposition

Tags: united-states, property

Property is a bundle of rights or legally protected interests, including:

- Right of possession, enjoyment, and use
- Unrestricted right of disposition
- Right to exclude others
- power of testimonial disposition

A property owner may hold all or just some of these rights.

**Please explain what is meant by "power of testimonial disposition". What exactly is testimonial disposition? And what does it have to do with property rights?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the power to bequeath something in your will. It is fundamentally related to property rights.

Comment: So it is just a more specific form of power of disposition then?